# The server principal “DevMe” is not able to access the database “CallManager” under the current security context

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to remove/ drop a users permissions but i keep getting the following error:

> The server principal “DevMe” is not able to access the database
>   “CallManager” under the             current security context.

My Stored proc to do this looks as follows:

```
USE [AuditIT]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[AdminDevUserDelete]    Script Date: 06/29/2012 08:54:27 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
--alter table AdminLog add HostName varchar(128) NULL DEFAULT HOST_NAME()

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AdminDevUserDelete]
    @SQLLoginName varchar(50) 
AS   

DECLARE @DatabaseName varchar(1000)

PRINT 'USE [master] DROP LOGIN [' + @SQLLoginName + ']'
EXEC ('USE [master] DROP LOGIN [' + @SQLLoginName + ']')

DECLARE CSDatabase CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT
        [Name]
    FROM
        [Master]..SysDatabases
    --WHERE
    --  --[sid] = 0x01
    --  [Name] NOT IN ('ReportSRV.Support','HelpDeskFacilities','QuestSoftware')
    ORDER BY
        dbid DESC
OPEN CSDatabase
FETCH NEXT FROM CSDatabase INTO @DatabaseName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    EXEC ('SELECT [Name] FROM [' + @DatabaseName + ']..SysUsers WHERE [Name] = ''' + @SQLLoginName + '''')
    IF @@RowCount > 0
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'USE [' + @DatabaseName + '] DROP USER [' + @SQLLoginName +']'
        EXEC ('USE [' + @DatabaseName + '] DROP USER [' + @SQLLoginName +']')
    END
    FETCH NEXT FROM CSDatabase INTO @DatabaseName
END
CLOSE CSDatabase
DEALLOCATE CSDatabase
```

**Could someone please explain how i could fix this problem?**

Comment: Do you have sys admin rights?

Comment: -1 just to lower this post on Google search, it has way too many SQL Injection problems and someone will stumble into it and copy it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- do not quote names manually, use the built in [QUOTENAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) function. Your code [does not handle correctly](http://xkcd.com/327/) database and user names that contain an embeded `]` character. Same goes for `'` quotes, use QUOTENAME again (it can quote both `[` and `'`, see the linked spec). Your code will break on names that contain embeded `'`.
- If you use SQL 2005 and beyond verbs like `DROP USER` then use the appropiate catalog views: [`sys.database_principals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187328.aspx) and [`sys.databases`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534.aspx).
- Always test your code on a case sensitive collation server. Your code will break because you use mixed case for catalog names. SQL server names are *all lowercase*.

Finaly, what is the problem causing the error you see? Is in the code you did not post, namely how you call this stored procedure. The error indicates that you are in EXECUTE AS sandbox mode, see [Understanding Execution Context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187096%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [Understanding Context Switching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191296%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx). You need to properly [code sign your procedure](http://rusanu.com/2006/03/01/signing-an-activated-procedure/) so that it can extend the context to the server level (since you're touching arbitrary database, cross database code signing won't be enough).

BTW if you're not under eXECUTE AS context then is plain and simply you don't have access to the database in question, so it's a mute question since you do not have the *rights* to do what you're trying to do. The other points still remain, and the proper wait to get the needed right for this procedure is still to use code signing, given what is trying to do...

Update:

Your C# code is also SQL injection prone... this is really a turkey shoot. Don't build your procedure name by `procedure = dataBase + ".." + procedure`!!

Comment: Thanks i will check out all these links, (I have a lot of reading to do.) But hope these links will help me understand. Thanks again. I put my C# code up if you would like to see that.

Comment: You say you're `dbowner`, that is not enough. You need access right to *all* those databases, and rights to query and drop users. dbowner applies only to *one* database. Are you dbowner of *every* database? Or are you a sysadmin? Is the procedure *always* going to be run by a sysadmin (in which case you should **really** fix all those SQL injections you have...)

Comment: I am haveing a Sysadmin account created for me now. SQL injections? The QUOTENAME?

Comment: It working fine now, just had a problem with not having and admin account.